# Flutter Navigator: Failed assertion ... !_debugLocked is not true on Navigator.pushNamed()

Tags: flutter, dart, stack-navigator

Well, let's say I have four screens, Main, Login, Home and Item. My desired "user-flow" is: Main -> Login (login is set as initialRoute) -> Home -> Item. I can get to the Home screen easily, but then I get this message: `Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4112 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.` I have found a looot of solutions, but none of them worked. Ended up with these codes:

1. Main

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'LetBike',
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme:
        GoogleFonts.josefinSansTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme),
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  ),
  initialRoute: "/",
  routes: {
    "/": (context) => LoginScreen(),
    "ForgotPassword": (context) => ForgotPassword(),
    "CreateNewAccount": (context) => CreateNewAccount(),
    HomePage.routeName: (context) => HomePage(),
    ItemPage.routeName: (context) => ItemPage()
  },
);
}
```

2. Login

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
HomePage.routeName,
arguments: snapshot.data);
```

3. Home

```
Navigator.of(context)
.pushNamed(ItemPage.routeName, arguments: item);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I had this error when I tried to pass a function with 1 arg (not calling it) to a big custom scaffold and then inside of it call in it. Amoung other stuff, that funcion was pushing a named route.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if you use

```
"WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(_routeName);"
```

instead of  `"Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(_routeName)"`

Answer (score 1):

Got it, the problem was in the Login screen, the working code is this:

```
if (snapshot.data.id < 0) {
                        return Text(
                            "username or password is incorrect");
                      } else {
                        Text("successful");
                        Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
                              HomePage.routeName,
                              arguments: snapshot.data);
                        });
                      }
```

the Future.delayed did the magic